# unable to set cookie for webview on Android version 17

Tags: android, android-webview

I use the following code to check for the Andriod version and set the domain accordingly.

```
domain = "domain.com";
int androidVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Log.d(TAG, "Android version" +androidVersion);
if(androidVersion >= 14){
    Log.d(TAG, "version is greater than 14");
    domain = ".domain.com";
}
```

and to set the cookie. i use the following code:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if(!cookie.equals("")){
    cookieManager.setCookie(domain, cookie);
}
try{
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}catch(IllegalStateException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This code works fine on version less than 17. When i check for the cookie just set on the javascript. i do not see it on android version 17.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you anywhere use ` cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to setCookie should be a full URL like "http://domain.com/". Also, if you are using a WebView, the cookie won't take effect immediately. You could try syncing it with CookieSyncManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html

Comment: im am using the cookieSyncManager over here..ill try using the full url. Thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you ??
this is what i wrote in my app and it works will.

```
Cookie sessionCookie = LoginWebView.cookie;
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webview.this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
if (sessionCookie != null) {
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName();
    Log.v(TAG, "sync cookies: " + cookieString);
    cookieManager.setCookie(domain, cookieString);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

}
```